# Problem with Auth0 login (and redirection) on deployed website

Tags: authentication, redirect, callback, auth0

I'm stuck on problem with Auth0 login. Everything worked fine on my local project (logging, redirection to homepage). After deploying this website to github.io some problems appeared.

When I use Auth0 I must define Allowed Callback URLs in Auth0 project dashboard.
For local project I wrote http://localhost:3000 in this text box and everything was good.
For project deployed on Github Pages I wrote https://michalgornicki.github.io/cats/ and after clicking login button there is this error:

[Error when I paste my website address (https://michalgornicki.github.io/cats/) to allowed callbacks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vP1Sr.png)

After writing https://michalgornicki.github.io in Allowed Callback URLs clicking login button redirects to https://michalgornicki.github.io link with info "There isn't a GitHub Pages site here."

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. See: "[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Answer (score 1):

I think I found source of this problem. In Index.js file in redirectUri={"} I had "window.location.origin" which worked on local project but linked to https://michalgornicki.github.io on deployed project. If I paste my website link in redirectUri it now works well.

Answer (score 0):

That actually works. Also remember to add the same link in the logout button code, or else the page will break when the user logs out.

```html
<button onClick={() => logout({ logoutParams: { returnTo: "https://username.github.io/your-app" } })}>
```